# check checkbox inside gridview either it is checked or not?

Tags: c#

I have gridview which contains the checkbox as templatefield. I have tried so hard but I am still unable to get the desired results, that is if check box is checked, than perform action-1 otherwise perform action-2, but everytime it is performing action-2. Below is my code I need little help from your side.

Gridview code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="final" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False";>
        <Columns>
<asp:BoundField DataField="name" HeaderText="Employee Name" SortExpression="date" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="ldate" HeaderText="Date Of Leave" SortExpression="ldate"
                   />
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Half/Full">
   <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1" runat="server">
                            <asp:ListItem Enabled="true" Value="Half">Half</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Enabled="true" Value="Full">Full</asp:ListItem>
           </asp:RadioButtonList>
   </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Approve">
    <ItemTemplate>
     <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

code I have made to check the radio and checkbox:

```
DataTable dtable = new DataTable();
dtable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Date", typeof(DateTime)));
dtable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Half/Full", typeof(float)));
dtable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Status", typeof(string)));
Session["dt"] = dtable;
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
conn.ConnectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["leave"].ConnectionString;
conn.Open();
foreach (GridViewRow gvrow in final.Rows)
{
     dtable=(DataTable)Session["dt"];
     CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)gvrow.FindControl("CheckBox1");
     if (chk != null & chk.Checked)
     {
          RadioButtonList rButton = (RadioButtonList)gvrow.FindControl("RadioButtonList1");
          if (rButton.SelectedValue == "Half")
          {
               //perform action-1
          }
          else
          {
              //perform action-1
          }
     }
  else
     {
          perform action-2
     }
}
```

everytime it's going into the last else...why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use logical and operator `&&` instead of bitwise `&` operator to combine the condition in the if statement.

*Change*

```
if (chk != null & chk.Checked)
```

*To*

```
if (chk != null && chk.Checked)
```

**Edit** based on comments by OP

You need to check that you bind the grid in such a way that it is not binded on postback.

```
if(!Page.IsPostBack)
{
       //bind here
}
```

Comment: Still not working.....that is if i checked the box than also it is considering as unchecked.....

Comment: Are you sure that you get true for chk.Checked?

Comment: Then it should go to else block, Have you debug the code ? You might be getting results of last row of gridview, change the checkbox of last row of gridview to see what happens?

Comment: Dear I think you didnt get my question at all...I have if else condition.if the condtion matched then perform action-1,else perform action-2...So my problem is i am not getting into action-1,that is if i check the checkbox than it should go through IF block..but it is going through ELSE block everytime.Even if i have checked the checkbox,it is conidering it as unchecked,My question is WHY THIS IS SO?I come to know this issue as i debug the code.

Comment: Thanks for clearing the confusion, can you check if you bind the grid in if(!Page.IsPostBack){//bind here} as if you bind grid on postback again you will loose the state of controls in the grid and checkbox1 will be false even you have check it before postback.

Comment: Can i give you a gold medal.....!!!!!! you are great.....no one has found issues in my code since last monday,but you found it in just 1 hour....thanks for this great support,my code is working as i want...thanks alot.....i am not able to upvote the answer as i am new to stackexchange.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are not binding the gridview again on page load, if you are then you must apply IsPostback check

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server"  OnCheckedChanged="CheckBox1_CheckedChanged"  AutoPostBack="true"/>

protected void CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)sender;
    GridViewRow gr = (GridViewRow)chk.Parent.Parent;
    RadioButtonList RadioButtonList1 = (RadioButtonList)gr.FindControl("RadioButtonList1");
    if (RadioButtonList1 != null)
    {
        RadioButtonList1.Items.FindByText("Full").Selected = true;
    }       
}
```